# Scraping text containing certain caracters and names in Python?

Tags: python, regex, lambda, beautifulsoup, quotes

I'm fairly new to python and working on a project in which I need all the quotes from certain people in a bunch of articles.

For this question I use this article as an example: https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/oct/17/jeffrey-clark-scrutiny-trump-election-subversion-scheme

Right now, with Lambda, I am able to scrape text containing the names of the people I am looking for with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/oct/17/jeffrey-clark-scrutiny-trump-election-subversion-scheme'
response = requests.get(url)
data=response.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
tags=soup.find_all('p')
words = ["Michael Bromwich"]
for tag in tags:
    quotes=soup.find("p",{"class":"dcr-s23rjr"}, text=lambda text: text and any(x in text for x in words)).text

print(quotes)
```

... which returns the block of text containing "Michael Bromwich", which in this case actually is a quote in the article. But when scraping 100+ articles, this does not do the job, as other blocks of text may also contain the indicated names without containing a quote. I only want the strings of text containing the quotes.

**Therefore, my question:**
Is it possible to print all HTML strings under the following criteria:

Text BEGINS with the caracter " (quotation mark) OR - (hyphen)
AND CONTAINS the names "Michael Bromwich" OR "John Johnson" etc.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need no regex here, `soup.find("p",{"class":"dcr-s23rjr"}, text=lambda t: t and (t.startswith("“") or t.startswith("-")) and any(x in t for x in words)).text` should do. Are the quotation marks always curly? Or do you need to support any kind of quotation marks? Same for hyphen: do you need to support any kind of dashes?

Comment: This does the job! Thank you. But it is not always curly quotation marks, no. How do I distinguish straight quotation marks from the other two quotations in t.startswith(""")?

Comment: See my answer, there is also a way to shorten this check to `t.strip()[0] in '“"-'`. If you need to add other quotes, add them as `t.strip()[0] in '''“"'‘-'''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not need the `for tag in tags` loop, you just need to use `soup.find_all` with your condition.

Next, you can check for the quotation marks or hyphen without any regex:

```py
quotes = [x.text for x in  soup.find_all("p",{"class":"dcr-s23rjr"}, text=lambda t: t and (t.startswith("“") or t.startswith('"') or t.startswith("-")) and any(x in t for x in words))]
```

The `(t.startswith("“") or t.startswith('"') or t.startswith("-"))` part will check if the text starts with `“`, `"` or `-`.

Or,

```py
quotes = [x.text for x in  soup.find_all("p",{"class":"dcr-s23rjr"}, text=lambda t: t and t.strip()[0] in '“"-' and any(x in t for x in words))]
```

The `t.strip()[0] in '“"-'` part checks if the `“"-` contains the first char of the stripped text value.